# Get Rolling Weeks Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get rolling 70-week, 65-week and 60-week (separate) data using SQL query. I know how to do this in years and months but how do I get a rolling 65-week data etc?

Comment: show us some code and your efforts. how do you define a rolling week? starting on a certain day of the week?

Comment: The rolling week should be data range in my where clause but that every time the query is run, it brings back data within the range of 65 weeks etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to know how many week are in a date span, say from 2016-01-01 to 2017-01-14.

In sql server you convert dates to int (days from 1900-01-01) like so `convert(int,DateColumn)`

So you can simply convert the dates to int, subtract, then divide by 7

For example

2016-01-01 = 42368

2017-01-14 = 42747

(42747 - 42368) / 7 = 54

A sql query would look something like this:

```
select (convert(int,GETDATE()) - convert(int,DateColumn)) / 7  as WeeksAgo  from Table
```

Used in a where statement to get last 65 weeks:

```
select * from Table where ((convert(int,GETDATE()) - convert(int,DateColumn)) / 7) < 65
```

Comment: Sorry if the question is not so clear to you. 
I want to retrieve data for that date range for the specific need of customers. Some want a rolling data of 60 weeks, some 65 and some 70 weeks. And that every time they get the query, they are looking at the for example data in the last 65 weeks, depending on the customer.

Comment: Ok, then this should work: 
select * from Table where ((convert(int,GETDATE()) - convert(int,DateColumn)) / 7) < 65

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on from the question but you can use a tally table

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATE = GETDATE() --Pick a starting Point

--tally tables http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/
--===== Conditionally drop 
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tally') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.Tally

--===== Create and populate the Tally table on the fly
SELECT TOP 11000 --equates to more than 30 years of dates
    IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
INTO dbo.Tally
FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
     Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2

--===== Add a Primary Key to maximize performance
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tally
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tally_N 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N) WITH FILLFACTOR = 100


SELECT
    DATEADD(WEEK, T.N, @StartDateTime) 'Week70'
FROM dbo.Tally T
WHERE
    T.N <= 70

SELECT
    DATEADD(WEEK, T.N, @StartDateTime) 'Week65'
FROM dbo.Tally T
WHERE
    T.N <= 65

SELECT
    DATEADD(WEEK, T.N, @StartDateTime) 'Week60'
FROM dbo.Tally T
WHERE
    T.N <= 60
```

Comment: Hello Cool_Br33ze,
Thank you. But how do you join to the Tally table to be able to use it in your where clause?

Comment: @dLight I'm not joining to the Tally table but selecting the N(umber) from it and using that in the `DATEADD` function. Tally are great way to avoid using CURSORs